# Python Vlookup fucction for list

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner.  Hope I could get some expert guidance on my problem.  Thank you very much.

I am trying to write a vlookup function using python.
I would hope the result to return the 3rd item in one of the list below.

I get below result
1300.72
None

May I know why I get the "NONE" after I run the script? I only expect it to return 1300.72
**strong text**
Below is my script

```
user_list = [["Account number","Currency","Balance"]
,["001-987654-003","USD",1300.72],["001-919202-100","EUR",105.01],
["001-905700-100","EUR",305.00],["001-908415-307","CHF",20804.98],
["011-974777-200","PLN",208.15],["001-931654-001","USD",450.7]]


lookuplist=user_list
lookupvalue="001-987654-003"
col_index=2


def vlookup(lookupvalue, lookuplist, col_index):
    x=lookupvalue.count(lookupvalue)
    if col_index<=3:
        print(user_list[x][col_index])
    else:
        print("out of range")

try:
    print(vlookup(lookupvalue, user_list, col_index))
except:
    print("NameError: name 'User_listxxx' is not defined")
```

Comment: recommend changing this to `if col_index<=len(lookuplist[0]):`. That way if the number of columns expands, it will still be valid.

Comment: what are you trying to do here `x=lookupvalue.count(lookupvalue)` ? You have `lookupvalue` on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are repeating `print`s.

Like if you do two prints, you always get a `None`:

```
>>> print(print('Hello World!'))
Hello World!
None
>>>
```

And the `type` of a `print` is `None`:

```
>>> type(print('Hello World!'))
Hello World!
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

So the way to fix your code is to change the following line:

```
    print(vlookup(lookupvalue, user_list, col_index))
```

To:

```
    vlookup(lookupvalue, user_list, col_index)
```

You already have a `print` in the `vlookup` function, so you should only use 1.